# Use weights in relative layout to have text views side by side

Tags: android, android-relativelayout, android-layout-weight

[image]Attached is the kind of layout i am trying to have in android layout. I have two text views placed next to each other each covering half of the place horizontally. And then i have other text views in the space below.

I was going to use relative layout, but then i could not get to place the two of them side by side and occupy same amount of space. Can someone help me with how can i achieve this?

Comment: then use linearlayout with weightsum=2 and weight=1 for both textview

Comment: linear layout within a relative layout?

Comment: no just linearlayout.

Comment: then how will i be able to add more views (the other 2 which are placed vertically below)

Comment: maker parent layout relative or linear. then add another linear with weightsum 2. and oter two textview below linearlayout

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this way

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="hello " />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="hello" />

</LinearLayout>

<TextView
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="hello " />

<TextView
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="hello" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: and how do i add the other two text views that are placed vertically below.

Answer (score 1):

Try below Logic.

```
LinearLayout
    - Vertical Orientation
    - LinearLayout
        -HorizontalOrientation
        -weightSum=2
            -TextView1 with weight=1
            -TextView2 with weight = 1
    -TextView 3
    -TextView 4
```